# Implement a method that generates the last insert id

Tags: java, jpql

I'm using JPQl and i want to implement a simple methode that generate my last insert Id into the table Test.

```
    public Integer lastInsertId(){
    String jpql="select t FROM Test t where id=:LAST_INSERT_ID()";
    Query query=entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
    return ;
}
```

Comment: ..and the problem is? What database vendor do you use? I don't see you trying to insert anything in your supplied query.

Comment: i want just to get the last insert id on the table Test.

Comment: Ok, so you want the id of the last inserted row in test. You could then either do `select max(t.id) from Test t`, if you want to use some function that would depend on your rdbms, and I don't thin jpql could be used (you need native SQL)

Comment: I have to work with JPQL i can't use native sql

Comment: Then if your id is generated sequentially you could just select the on with the highest id.

Comment: like this select t.id from Test t order by t.id desc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the last id, given that your id's are generated sequentially, you could do this:

```
em.createQuery("select max(t.id) from Test t", Integer.class).getSingleResult();
```

Comment: and the methode return what?

Comment: This invocation returns an Integer (adjust it to whatever class your id is, Long ,etc..)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I know what you want actually but you can find last added entity:

```
String jpql = "select t FROM Test t order by t.id desc";
```

And get your id something like this:

```
query.setMaxResults(1).getResultList();
```

Comment: i don't want the last added enity but the id of the last added entity

Comment: so you can using "select t.id from Test t order by t.id desc"

Comment: @Alex and the methode return what?